# call different method with same string in different value

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two methods in my .m file .And i want to access by different values but in my Facebook variable gives nil value but if i use only one line and remove second line of object for key then it work fine for one method .
How i do this which work for my both methods

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
user=[defaults objectForKey:@"userid"];
facebook=[defaults objectForKey:@"FACEBOOKprofile"];
facebook =[defaults objectForKey:@"VLCC"];

if ([facebook isEqualToString:@"VLCCFACEBOOK"])
{
    [self FacebookRecord];
}
else if([facebook isEqualToString:@"VLCC"])
{
    [self VlccRecord];
}
```

Comment: would you want to acces the two methods are same time or based on any one condition....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assume that

**Choice-1**

```
// for accessing the both condition in same time
```

Initially Store the `UserDefault value based` on your method.

if you are access with `facebook` , on that time store the string like

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:"VLCCFACEBOOK" forKey:@"FACEBOOKprofile"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

if you are access with `VLCC` , on that time store the string like

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:"VLCC" forKey:@"VLCCprofile"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

and retrieve the both and check like

```
if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
objectForKey:@"FACEBOOKprofile"]isEqualToString:@"VLCCFACEBOOK"])
{
[self FacebookRecord];
}
if([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
objectForKey:@"VLCCprofile"] isEqualToString:@"VLCC"])
{
[self VlccRecord];
}
```

**Choice-2**

```
// for accessing single condition on single time
```

if you are access with `facebook` , on that time store the string like

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:"VLCCFACEBOOK" forKey:@"FACEBOOKprofile"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

if you are access with `VLCC` , on that time store the string like

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:"VLCC" forKey:@"FACEBOOKprofile"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

and retrieve the both and check like

```
if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
objectForKey:@"FACEBOOKprofile"]isEqualToString:@"VLCCFACEBOOK"])
{
[self FacebookRecord];
}
else if([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
objectForKey:@"FACEBOOKprofile"] isEqualToString:@"VLCC"])
{
[self VlccRecord];
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Anbu sir..Your suggestion always help me..Thanks a lot....I choose choice 2

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the `[self VlccRecord]` method will always get called because you are overwriting the facebook variable.

```
facebook=[defaults objectForKey:@"FACEBOOKprofile"];
facebook =[defaults objectForKey:@"VLCC"];
```

If you are looking to append the two strings : Then use the stringbyAppendingString method.

Answer (score 0):

```
int a = 10;
a = 20;
print >> a; //20

int a = 10;
print1 >> a; //10
a = 20;
print2 >> a; //20
```

Here, 
a = facebook;
print1 = [self FacebookRecord];
print2 = [self VlccRecord];

*I believe you'll understand.*